# Keeping original cell values when replacing NA values using nearest neighbour with focal function of R?

Tags: r

The following code for replacing NA values was posted by Jeffery Evans. This function smooths the whole raster. I only want to fill the gaps of the NA cells keeping the other values in place. How do I adjust the function so that it only replaces NA values with the?

```
library(raster)
  r <- raster(matrix(1:16, nrow=8, ncol=8))
  r[r==12] <- NA

fill.na <- function(x, i=5) {
  if( is.na(x)[i] ) {
    return( round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),0) )
  } else {
    return( round(x[i],0) )
  }
}

r2 <- focal(r, w = matrix(1,3,3), fun = fill.na, 
            pad = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE )

as.matrix(r)
as.matrix(r2)
```

Comment: I don't use r but when compiling a similar function in another platform I created a focal raster then went back with a condition if (IsNull(r)) r = r2; unless you can iterate the raster cell by cell and do a focal statistic on a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't "smooth the whole raster". If you do `as.matrix(r) - as.matrix(r2)` you'll get TRUE everywhere except the NAs.

Examine the code:

```
fill.na <- function(x, i=5) {
  if( is.na(x)[i] ) {
    return( round(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),0) )
  } else {
    return( round(x[i],0) )
  }
}
```

If the fifth element is `NA` (`if(is.na(x)[i]`), then return the mean of the 3x3 neighbourhood, excluding any NAs. This mean is then rounded to the nearest integer. The fifth element is chosen because in a 3x3 set of nine cells, the fifth one is the centre cell.

If the fifth element isn't NA, then return the rounded value of the fifth element, in other words, if its an integer, it returns the same value, doing no smoothing or other processing. So `r2[i,j]==r[i,j]` is not NA and is integers.

If you don't want the process to round the values at all, just remove the `round` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it looks like this is smoothing the raster is because the else return is rounding the x[i]. Try replacing, `return(round(x[i],0)` with `return(x[i])`.